# Use Defined Variable with egrep to Match Contents Inside Text File

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

I have a text file with numerous four-letter codes. I need to use the contents of this text file to match the content with the text inside of another text file and then `grep` out the contents of the matched lines to a new text file.

I can't get the below code to work after much avail...

```
while read site

do

egrep -n "${site}" cy.00.txt > file.txt

done < /home/weather/newsites.txt
```

newsites.txt:

```
KBED
KBOS
KDCA
```

Expected Output:

```
832:KBED   XXX    7/10/2015  0000 UTC                      
1060:KBOS   XXX    7/10/2015  0000 UTC                      
1630:KDCA   XXX    7/10/2015  0000 UTC
```

Comment: You always write to the same file, so you will have result of last grep only

Comment: You didn't include sample data from `cy.00.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do wihout any loop:

```
egrep -nf newsites.txt cy.00.txt >file.txt
```

And also consider using `grep -E` instead of `egrep`.
`man grep` says:

> egrep is the same as grep -E.  ...   **Direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep is deprecated**,
>          but is provided to allow historical applications that  rely  on  them  to  run
>          unmodified.

Comment: This is not outputting the egrep results to "file.txt"

Comment: @A It does, I have tested it. check if you are using the right files.

Comment: @AaronPerry newsites.txt is the file which contains patterns and c.00.txt is the file that needs to be matched.